# Two decimal format for ListView column

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I format the `TotalPrice` to 2 decimal point?

I pass a double value to the `<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" />`

For example I pass in 10, I want to show 10.00 in ListView column?

Code:

```
 <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="50">
     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Width="50" >
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice, StringFormat=Now {0:c}!}"
```

See [BindingBase.StringFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx)

Comment: Should be StringFormat='{}{0:#.00}'}? Thanks for pointing out the function.

Comment: My Apologies, figured since it was a money I thought the Dollar sign would help.

Answer (score 2):

Use can also use this for the binding up to the two digit decimal places

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice, StringFormat=Now {0:.00}!}"
```

Here you can also this